# Examples of Financial Institutions that Compute Interest Atypically?

Tags: algebra, examples, precalculus

Are there examples of financial institutions that compound their interest more frequently than once-a-month? Are there examples of financial institutions that consider continually compounded interest in practice?

Comment: There are, or used to be in the US, home mortgages with payments every 2 weeks rather than monthly. In addition to having an 'extra month' payment per year, paying down the principle on a shorter time period reduced the overall amount paid in interest.

Comment: I believe they mostly use contuously compounded interest. That's why they all report APY (annual percentage yield), so that the different methods won't prevent consumers from comparing properly.

Comment: @Sue VanHattum Maybe I'm cynical, but I thought they mostly use APY because it's slightly higher. I have a vague memory of computing the APR of one of my accounts from the advertised APY (assuming it compounds monthly) and getting a "nice" percentage for the APR, whereas the advertised APY wasn't such a round number.

Comment: Disclosing APY is a federal requirement for banks in the U.S., by the Truth in Savings Act from 1993 (§ 230.4(b)(1): "An institution must disclose both the 'annual percentage yield' and the 'interest rate,' using those terms." https://www.federalreserve.gov/boarddocs/caletters/2007/0707/07-07_attachment.pdf